# Doubts with separability of Differential Equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have an exercise where I should solve some separable ODEs. But I have problems with the following: $ y' = t + cos^2(y) $ and $ 2 y' = \sqrt{4y + t^2} - t $. They are supposed to be separable, but I have no idea why...

Comment: **They are supposed to be separable,** who said that?

Comment: The exercise itself. The others ODE (not included on this post) are clearly separable... But I think this two not. Maybe there is a mistake.

Comment: yes, these are not separable. seems like mistake in book.

Comment: When $x$ & $y$ are variables & $t$ is Constant , then we can make it separable. When $y$ & $t$ are variables , then we can not make it separable. There might be "mistakes/typos" in that text book.

Comment: None of them are separable, however the second one can be transformed into $y=ty'+y'^2$ by squaring both sides. This is a type of [Clairaut's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation) with $f(x)=x^2$. It can be solved by differentiating both sides, in which case we obtain the form $0=y''(t+2y)$. This is solvable, and removing the false solutions gets us $y(t)=ct+c^2$ which indeed solves the original equation.

Comment: The second equation can be rewritten as $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\sqrt{4y+t^2}\right)=1$.